Do editor scripts impact game performance?

Do Editor scripts or custom editor windows with UIToolkit have an effect on game or engine performance? Even after build?

Do they get built with the game when exporting it?




Editor scripts and custom editor windows using UIToolkit do not affect game or engine performance after the build. They are enclosed within #if UNITY_EDITOR directives, compiled into separate editor-only assemblies, and stripped out during the build process. This ensures they only enhance the development workflow and do not impact the final game.

No, editor scripts and custom editor windows with UIToolkit do not get included in the build when exporting the game. They are enclosed in #if UNITY_EDITOR directives and are only used within the Unity Editor, ensuring they are excluded from the final build.


